# Error in recode comand in 'R'

Tags: r, recode

How to overcome this?? Many thanks! Using 'car' library

```
    data3$Edu=recode(data3$Edu, "'Incomplete secondary school: technical/ vocational type'=4")
Error in recode(data3$Edu, "'Incomplete secondary school: technical/ vocational type'=4") : 

  in recode term: 'Incomplete secondary school: technical/ vocational type'=4
  message: Error in parse(text = range[[1]][1]) : 
  <text>:1:1: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
1: 'Incomplete secondary school
    ^
```

Comment: It could be because of `/`.  Is it a character or factor column?  One option would be using `base R` i.e. `data3$Edu[data3$Edu =="Incomplete secondary school: technical/ vocational type"] <- 4` (works for character column).  For `factor` class, change the `levels`

Comment: That's a factor column, There's 9 levels needed to be recoded, and I hoped to do this in one comand. In example :    data3$Edu=recode(data3$Edu, "'No formal education'=1")
This one is recoded normally.

Comment: Sorry, bro, my bad =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to remove those special characters and then do the `recode`

```
with(data3, recode(gsub("[/:]", "", Edu), 
     "'Incomplete secondary school technical vocational type' = 4"))
```

Or we can use `base R` methods like assigning the `levels` to the new level

```
levels(data3$Edu)[levels(data3$Edu)=="Incomplete secondary school: technical/ vocational type"] <- 4
data3
#               Edu
#1                4
#2   Something else
#3 Some other thing
#4                4
```

#### Update

As the OP wanted to recode multiple values to something else, we can use `match`.  Here I am changing the 1st and 3rd `level` to new values.

```
levels(data3$Edu)[match(levels(data3$Edu)[c(1,3)], levels(data3$Edu) ) ] <- c(4, 1)
data3
#               Edu
#1                4
#2                1
#3 Some other thing
#4                4
```

If the OP want to change all the levels to some numeric values, we can coerce the `factor` levels to numeric directly

```
as.integer(data3$Edu)
#[1] 1 3 2 1
```

The values can be changed by setting the `levels` differently i.e.

```
as.integer(factor(data3$Edu, levels = levels(data3$Edu)[c(1,3,2)]))
#[1] 1 2 3 1
```

#### data

```
data3 <- data.frame(Edu = c('Incomplete secondary school: technical/ vocational type', 
             'Something else',
             'Some other thing',
             'Incomplete secondary school: technical/ vocational type' 
              ))
```

Comment: Well, I'm kinda new to R, but base R method with 'levels' helped. 

But there's something wrong with gsub.
data3$Edu=gsub("[:], " ", data3$Edu)

Sends me 'NULL' after levels(data3$Edu) comand.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, thankfuly to @akrun I've combined his suggestion and mine:

```
data1$Edu=as.factor(gsub("[/:]","",as.character(levels(data1$Edu))[data1$Edu]))
data1$Edu=as.numeric(recode(data1$Edu, "'No formal education'=1;
                 'Incomplete primary school'=2;
                 'Complete primary school'=3;
                 'Incomplete secondary school technical vocational type'=4;
                 'Complete secondary school technical vocational type'=5;
                 'Incomplete secondary school university-preparatory type'=6;
                 'Complete secondary school university-preparatory type'=7;
                 'Some university-level education, without degree'=8;
                 'University - level education, with degree'=9"))
```

Hope it can help someone. Thanks @akrun again!